# I am stuck in creating a simple verification. How do I take the input entered by user and verify with my data?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take the user input and iterate through my data to check whether it matches or not.
How do I verify if the user entered input matches with my data.

```js
const userInput = document.querySelector(".ID");
const button = document.querySelector(".login");
const data = [
  { userName: "Jon", userId: 1, admin: true },
  { userName: "Mike", userId: 2, admin: false },
  { userName: "Martha", userId: 3, admin: false },
];


function checkUser() {
  const id = userInput.value;
  data.forEach((user) => {
    if (id === user.userId) {
      console.log("Welcome");
    } else {
      console.log("Incorrect ID");
    }
  });
}

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkUser();
});
```

```html
<input class="ID" />
<input type="button" class="login" value="login" />
```

Comment: 1 !== "1" - use a string in the object

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Please be brief as I am new to this topic.

Comment: Just change `userId: 1` to `userId: "1"` etc

Answer (score -1):

Input element values are string. For your code to work, you must declare your `data.userId` as strings.

So it must be:

```
    const data = [
    { userName: "Jon", userId: "1", admin: true },
    { userName: "Mike", userId: "2", admin: false },
    { userName: "Martha", userId: "3", admin: false },
    ];
```

If you don't want to use strings as userId, you should change the logical operator of your conditional statement into `==` instead of `===` so it would ignore data types.